# User-defined Python 3 function for finding prime numbers not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a function to solve for prime numbers, but when used in the console to return a result, it sometimes also returns odd numbers as True. Code written below for reference.

```
def StartingisPrime(a):
   if a>1:
#running the input stepwise
    for i in range (2,a):
#dividing the input by each number to test if prime or no
       if (a%i)==0:
           return False
           break
       else:
           return True
#non-positive answers
   else:
        return False
```

Result:

```
StartingisPrime(9)
Out[15]: True
```

Appreciate greatly any light that can be shed for this matter :(

Comment: In the first iteration of your for loop, you take 2, check if 9 is divisible by 2, answer is no therefore "else" is triggered and True is returned and program terminated (doesn't continue iterating onto the next steps of the for loop)

Comment: Please fix your formatting and indentations. You must see that this post is unreadable. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, that else is messing things up and in fact you don't even need it. Also you don't need to break after a return, since return itself breaks the operation by nature.

Here is an edit to your attempt, with a little extra `assert`ion touch. (Assertion is a wonderful and easy way to make sure sanity requirements are met.)

Note: No complexity improvement made, just your code is fixed.

```
def StartingisPrime(a):
    assert a > 1, "Prime only applies to numbers greater than 1!"
    # running the input stepwise
    for i in range (2, a):
    # dividing the input by each number to test if prime or no
       if a % i == 0:
           return False
    # if the loop is exploited and no divisor is found then the number is prime
    return True
 
print(StartingisPrime(9)) # False
print(StartingisPrime(11)) # True
```

Comment: You can optimize the complexity by setting the upper bound of the for-loop to the square root of a + 1.

Comment: Yeah makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pythonic way of handling functions that returns True or False. One of them is using any or all function or using rich comparison. I have a 2 liner that returns True or False depending on the input.

```
def isprime(n):
    return all( n%i !=0 for i in range(2, n))
```

What the code above does is first creating a generator exp containing `True` or `False`. If a number is prime,  it will contain only `True` for each `n℅i != 0`. So we used `all` to check if all is True (prime) anything else ain't prime.

The function doesn't handle 0 and 1, you can fix that!  Plus it's more efficient to find `range(2, sqrt(n))` instead of n. It's trival here since our generator exp don't consume space like when we used a list comp. But just so you know

**Here's a good list,  set, and dict comphension guide by Treyhunner**

https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def StartingisPrime(a):
   if a>1:
#running the input stepwise
    for i in range (2,a):
#dividing the input by each number to test if prime or no
       if (a%i)==0:
           x=0
           break
       else:
           x=1
       
#non-positive answers
   else:
        x = 0
    
   if x == 0:
        return False
   else:
        return True
```

Based on Deceze suggestion!!

```
def StartingisPrime(a):
   if a>1:
#running the input stepwise
    for i in range (2,a):
#dividing the input by each number to test if prime or no
       if (a%i)==0:
           x=False
           break
       else:
           x=True
       
#non-positive answers
   else:
        x = False
   
   return x
```

Comment: Why not set `x` to `True` or `False` directly and just `return x` at the end…?

Comment: Yes we can..I wrote this so that it is more easy for the OP to understand..what mistake the OP is making!!

Comment: Save iterations by setting upper loop bound to `a/2+1`, half of the iterations are completely unnecesary

Comment: @Ruli In fact, the upper loop bound should be the square root of a + 1. 
For example: If a = 100 you would only iterate to 10 and not to 50.

Comment: @Gledi thanks for correcting me, I have added answer with such solution as nobody included it

Answer (score -1):

FaithAkici, Rahul, deceze and Anya's helpful suggestions worked. I wanted to `sqrt (a)` but it kept giving me a `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

The final code I used was:

```
def StartingisPrime(a):
    assert a > 0, "Prime only applies to positive numbers!"
    if a>1:
        for i in range (2,a):
            if (a%i)==0:
                return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Hi, glad your question was answered. Please mark the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm a new user, apologies for not knowing the convention here but really appreciate the help :)